# How to get Hash of function with many returns types?

Tags: contract-invocation

I have a method :

```
function getBalance(address _add) public view 
            returns (uint256, string memory, bool, uint256, uint256, uint256) {
        return(accountBalance[_add].amount,
            accountBalance[_add].valueDateTime,
            accountBalance[_add].credit,
            accountBalance[_add].bankId,
            accountBalance[_add].branchId,
            accountBalance[_add].accountId);
    }
```

I have tried many ways to get some hash which will work for my json rpc.
But I am not able to get through.
Tried combinations which didn't work :

> web3.sha3('getBalance(address) returns (uint256, string,bool,uint256,uint256,uint256)');
>   "0x2560a3f9b1f28442f55de402532d55bffa0794ee53310ed4dc65d3dda6a8fc4b"
>
> web3.sha3('getBalance(address) returns (uint256, string memory,bool,uint256,uint256,uint256)');
>   "0x963fc1d2d6f67d205b9f56340f6f9853ea45969dcc25182fbd9705abe74cfcbf"
>
> web3.sha3('getBalance(address) view returns (uint256, string memory,bool,uint256,uint256,uint256)');
>   "0xdcd78e55620fe9302439c2ccb0c23d69f7399b61e3b0b6c9c15142f85fe6b3fa"
>
> web3.sha3('getBalance(address) view returns (uint256,string,bool,uint256,uint256,uint256)');
>   "0x97abd19f4ac051fb6b277f2c947801a9120e0935a7225ff322d1cf2a2dcb1b8a"
>
> web3.sha3('getBalance(address) view returns (uint256,string memory,bool,uint256,uint256,uint256)');
>   "0xc174d458674c0f18ffbf8addc06d41eb80a9bcab82d31fee290be4368339840e"
>
> web3.sha3('getBalance(address) returns (uint256,string,bool,uint256,uint256,uint256)');
>   "0x02cd8e0e733ce057edefbb512190a6e6ecdae93ea96aa413d83cc7ad5c3d312c"
>
> web3.sha3('getBalance(address) returns (uint256,string memory,bool,uint256,uint256,uint256)');
>   "0x48a0f2e06a2c0c3b033efbad3ecde8042792381edf9c600c2d1f7fb35a43c986"
>
> web3.sha3('getBalance(address)');
>   "0xf8b2cb4f3943230388faeee074f1503714bff212640051caba01411868d14ae3"

Can someone please help.

Comment: The last one is correct: `web3.sha3('getBalance(address)')`. You'll want just the first four bytes (`0xf8b2cb4f`). If you're having trouble using that, please share the code / HTTP request you're making that uses that function selector.

Comment: @smarx That is not working for me.
This is the request :
{"jsonrpc":"2.0", "method":"eth_call", "params":[{"from": "eth.accounts[0]", "to": "0x9d13c6d3afe1721beef56b55d303b09e021e27ab", "data": "0xf8b2cb4f000000000000000000000000ed9d02e382b34818e88b88a309c7fe71e65f419d", "gas":4700000}],"latest", "id":1}

Comment: Response am getting is :
<error>
      <code>-32602</code>
      <message>invalid argument 0: json: cannot unmarshal hex string without 0x prefix into Go struct field CallArgs.from of type common.Address</message>
   </error>

If I use this from geth console, I get something which seems correct :
var result = web3.eth.call({
    to: "0x9d13c6d3afe1721beef56b55d303b09e021e27ab",
    data: "0xf8b2cb4f000000000000000000000000ed9d02e382b34818e88b88a309c7fe71e65f419d"
});

Comment: It looks like you're sending the quoted string `"eth.accounts[0]"` in the RPC request instead of the actual address.

Comment: @smarx yeah, you are right. that changed the error to :
      <message>invalid character 'e' looking for beginning of value</message>
Seems now something wrong in data.

Comment: Can you share the latest request?

Comment: This doesn't return anything, but no error as well :
{"jsonrpc":"2.0", "method":"eth_call", "params":[{"from": "0xed9d02e382b34818e88b88a309c7fe71e65f419d","to": "0x9d13c6d3afe1721beef56b55d303b09e021e27ab", "data": "0xf8b2cb4f000000000000000000000000ed9d02e382b34818e88b88a309c7fe71e65f419d"}], "id":1}

Comment: Could you explain what you mean? There's no response at all from the server? Does it time out?

Comment: Finally I got it .. I had to add the "latest" in params and correct my data.
Request :
{"jsonrpc":"2.0", "method":"eth_call", "params":[{"from": "0xed9d02e382b34818e88b88a309c7fe71e65f419d","to": "0x9d13c6d3afe1721beef56b55d303b09e021e27ab", "data": "0xf8b2cb4f000000000000000000000000ed9d02e382b34818e88b88a309c7fe71e65f419d"},"latest"], "id":1}
Response :
0x64000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000007b00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Thanks a lot for your help. :)

Answer (score 1):

The return type of a function is not part of this signature.

See [here](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/abi-spec.html#function-selector) for more details (specifically, take a look at the note).

If you want to encode your function, then you can try this (web3.js v1.x):

```
function encode(abiArray, functionName, functionArgs) {
    for (const object of abiArray)
        if (object.name == functionName)
            return web3.eth.abi.encodeFunctionCall(object, functionArgs);
    throw new Error("function " + functionName + " does not exist");
}
```